# replace() removes the whole word not the character

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with prices in $. I want to do calculations on it but the $ makes it impossible. I'm trying to remove it using  `df.iloc[:, 4].replace("$", " ", regex=True)` but unfortunately nothing changes. If I add `inplace=True` then whe whole word disappears. What am I doing wrong? Tried many stackoverflow posts but nothing works. I cant use `str.replace()` because its about the whole column not one word.

My code:

```
    order_id    quantity    item_name   choice_description  item_price
0   1   1   Chips and Fresh Tomato Salsa    NaN $2.39
1   1   1   Izze    [Clementine]    $3.39
2   1   1   Nantucket Nectar    [Apple] $3.39
3   1   1   Chips and Tomatillo-Green Chili Salsa   NaN $2.39
4   2   2   Chicken Bowl    [Tomatillo-Red Chili Salsa (Hot), [Black Beans...   $16.98
... ... ... ... ... ...
4617    1833    1   Steak Burrito   [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Rice, Black Beans, Sour ...   $11.75
4618    1833    1   Steak Burrito   [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Rice, Sour Cream, Cheese...   $11.75
4619    1834    1   Chicken Salad Bowl  [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Pinto...   $11.25
4620    1834    1   Chicken Salad Bowl  [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Lettu...   $8.75
4621    1834    1   Chicken Salad Bowl  [Fresh Tomato Salsa, [Fajita Vegetables, Pinto...   $8.75
```

Then I call function replace() but the table stays the same:
`df.iloc[:, 4].replace("$", " ", regex=True)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Since your question is about `replace()`, there is no need for a dataframe. Just use a string. We should be able to copy/paste and run your code ourselves. Also show the output you get and explain what you want it to be instead.

Comment: I don't think that you want `regex=True`. `$` is a special character that "Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string". See the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:, 4].replace("\$", " ", regex=True)
```

Alternatively:

```
df.iloc[:, 4].replace("$", " ")
```

Comment: Alternatively, remove `regex=True` from the original code.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to introduce a space `" "`?

Comment: well Idk the OP asked for that

Comment: @Synthase - thanks! the firsl option worked for me! I tried the second one before but with no success.